# How to close/start a server socket correctly at button press JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, serversocket

I just want to know if there is a correct way to close a server socket and start it again using the same port it was using. I am writing a FTP program and the user can shut it down or start the server by GUI. Now, I click the button to start it, everything works fine, click it again, it stops, but when trying to attempt to start it, it throws an exception.

```
Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

My code is as follows

```
public static void listen(int port) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("FTP Server Started on Port Number " + port);
    while (online) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for Connection ...");
        transferfile t = new transferfile(soc.accept());
    }
    soc.close();
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket(port);
```

Change this to

```
ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket();
soc.setReuseAddress(true);
soc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

This tells TCP to allow the socket to bind to a port that is already in use, probably by old `TIME_WAIT` states.